# UIPageViewControlerDataSource and UiWebView for displaying on pages

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uipageviewcontroller, ibooks

I want to develop an ePub-reader application using `UIPageViewController` and `UIWebView` for displaying book pages. So I can make pages from different chapters by perform offset with JavaScript-strings.

The question is how can I implement the `UIPageViewControlerDataSource delegate` working in rightful way? When I prepare some page for showing I should use `UIWebView` methods and `UIWebView delegate` methods which are working only if `webView` is on the screen yet.
I tried to make underlying `webView` under `pageViewController` for making calculus linked with ePub chapters paging but I can't drag loaded content on the page.

Does anyone know how is it implemented in iBooks or the same apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy solution could be:

- subclass `UIPageViewController`, make it conform to `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` and `UIWebViewDelegate` protocols and set `self` as datasource in the `-viewDidLoad` override
- implement `pageViewController:viewControllerAfterViewController:` and `pageViewController:viewControllerBeforeViewController:` (UIPageViewControllerDataSource protocol methods) so that they return a new `UIViewController` containing a `UIWebView` displaying your data.

  ```
  - (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
  {
      UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
      UIWebView *webview = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
      webview.delegate = self;

      // Here you can call - (void)loadData:(NSData *)data MIMEType:(NSString *)MIMEType textEncodingName:(NSString *)encodingName baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
      // to load your web page as you need

      vc.view = webview;

      return vc;
  }
  ```

Of course you have to complete the code stub. You should setup a mechanism to distinguish between viewControllers to be able to return the next and the previous page (i.e. I do it with a UIPageViewController subclass declaring a `pageNumber` property, but I am sure there are more elegant ways to do it..)

Comment: But what about this line in Apple's UIPageViewController Class Reference:
"This class is not intended to be subclassed." ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "UIViewController subclass", not UIPageViewController (now corrected in the answer). Anyway, the sentence you quoted with iOS 6 documentation has become: `This class is generally used as-is but may be subclassed in iOS 6 and later.` - a softer policy.. More in general, as far as I understand it, this usually just means that one should not try to change the default behaviour of the controller in subclasses.

Comment: Ah no ok sorry again, I really meant to subclass UIPageViewController :) So, the rest of the previous comment should answer your doubt

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try implement this solution. Seems to be legit =)